# how to use appendChild in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am getting the image url of the uploaded image in my js script on my front-end.

```
document.getElementById("url").value = result_url;
      var imgUrl = result_url;
      Node.appendChild(imgUrl);
      console.log(imgUrl)
```

it is working, but now I am trying to append it to the body, so it displays the users uploaded image. Is this the right way to do it Node.appendChild is not working. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you want the image URL in text to appear in the body or the actual image as an `img` element?

Comment: @plalx the actual image as an img element :)

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide an [mcve]. Use the stack snippet feature of the question editor to provide a live demo. What is `Node`? What HTML is this operating on?

Comment: If this question is about DOM manipulation with client-side JS, why is it tagged [tag:node.js] and [tag:ejs]?

Comment: `imgUrl` appears to be a string variable, if you're setting the value of an element to it. Also `Node.appendChild` is the interface. You need to call `appendChild` on an actual object that implements `Node`, like an element.

Comment: Oh crumbs, I assumed `Node` was an undefined variable and not the Node function.

Comment: I get the impression that your experience level is such that you should be working through [an introductory tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) before dealing with specific problems.

Comment: @Quentin I appreciate the comments and advice. I don't do much js scripting for front end, so it's all a learning process. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, I believe it's self-explanatory. `appendChild` must be called on the node instance (e.g. `document.body`). Furthermore, you have to create an actual `img` element as you can't just add a `String` as a `Node`.

```js
const imgSrc = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1c/cd/18/1ccd18916cc5e4a2840ea084ef9c36b1.jpg';

document.body.appendChild(newImg(imgSrc));

function newImg(src) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = src;
  return img;
}
```